# write PowerShell script to count number of special char and space present in a text file and replace them with tab

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

1. Text file name "test.txt"
2. Present file content

   ```
   hello!my@name$is*swaraj mohapatra
   11!12#13%14$
   ```
3. Required file content

   ```
   hello my name is swaraj mohapatra
   11 12 13 14 15
   ```
4. Output:

   ```
   This file contains 9 special characters
   ```

---

```
$content = Get-Content "test.txt"
$c = ($b.ToCharArray() -eq '!').count        //can check for only one special character
Write-Output "This file contains $c special characters"
$tab = "`t"
@(ForEach ($line in $b){$a.Replace('  ',$tab).Replace(' ',$tab).Replace('!',$tab)}) > $content
Write-Output "file content without any special char "
$b
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to replace all characters that are not letters or numbers, you may do the following:

```
$content = Get-Content test.txt
# Matches method will match all occurrences of special characters
if ($count = [regex]::Matches($content,'[^\p{L}\p{N}]').Count) {
    Write-Output "This file contains $count special characters"
}
$UpdatedContent = Set-Content -Value ($content -replace '[^\p{L}\p{N}]',"`t") -Path test.txt -PassThru
Write-Output "File content without special characters"
$UpdatedContent
```

**Explanation:**

Since `-replace` uses regex matching, you can set a matching pattern and a replacement string. `[^]` is a character class that does not match (`^`) anything inside. `\p{L}` matches a unicode letter. `\p{N}` matches a unicode number. Each special character is replaced with a PowerShell tab.

If you want consecutive special characters to be replaced by a single tab rather than one tab per character, you may use `'[^\p{L}\p{N}]+'` ***in the replace expression only*** because we want each individual special character counted in the counting expression. The `+` matches one or more of the previous matched character.

If there are expected to be non-English letters that you also want to replace, you may opt for `'[^a-zA-Z0-9]'` as your regex match.